# Which devilish person am I?

Tags: riddle

Because my first riddle was solved so fast, I tried to create something short, but more diffcult.

```
Hint 5 added
```

> First, I was named by a cock, as the first.
>   Second, I was maybe named like a
>   cock, but before the first.
>   At the end you have to pay me 0.1$, but the half could also be the beginning of the first.
>   Do you know who I am?

Hint1:

> Knowing my first riddle could help solving this one

Hint2:

> Cock has no dirty meaning, i am talking about the animal (Could also have used rooster, but as far as I know this is only used in US)...

Hint3:

> Pat G's idea could help for a partial solution

Hint 4:

> First has 4 different meanings in the riddle. firstname, first-part(Position), first-part(time) and first as translated word. (not necessarly in this order)

Hint 5:

> 0.1$ is not **one** Nickel. But the half is.

Comment: Chad Kroeger? Because 0,1$ is a dime and half of a dime is a nickel. So, nickelback => chad kroeger, I don't even

Comment: @pat G:No, it is not chad kroeger or nickelback what i had in mind, I dont know how this could fit the the other parts...

Comment: As i said: "I don't even". As in : "I don't even know where this idea came from".

Comment: Dick Nicholson!

Comment: am confused... is this a chicken or what?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are:

> Niccolò Paganini (1782-1840) the Italian violinist and composer

The elements play a major role in this puzzle.

First, I was named by a cock, as the first.

> Otto Hahn first gave the name Proactinum (Pa) to element 91.  Hahn in German translates to rooster/cock.  Pa is the first part of the last name.

Second, I was maybe named like a cock, but before the first.

> Gallium (Ga) was named for the latin *gallus*, or cock → PaGa

At the end you have to pay me 0.1$

> $0.1 is equal to two nickels, and Nickel is Ni, hence the NiNi at the end of the name → PaGaNiNi

but the half could also be the beginning of the first.

> Half of $0.1 is just one Nickel (Ni), the first part of the first name (Niccolò)

I am a devilish person because:

> According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niccol%C3%B2_Paganini), he was suspected to be associated with the Devil, and there was a 2013 movie called [The Devil's Violinist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Devil's_Violinist) about him.

Comment: Well done. You solved the riddle correct. Proactinum was named protosactinum First and protos is "the first" in greek

Comment: Dammit, I read through a list of discoverers of elements looking for cocks and completely missed Hahn. Excellent!

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I did as well, but only got to Hahn after I'd figured out that we probably needed Pa in the puzzle!

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps you are

> Gallium

First, I was named by a cock, as the first.

> Lecoq de Boisbaudran was the discoverer of gallium and his name means "the cock".

Second, I was maybe named like a cock, but before the first.

> *Gallus* is the Latin for a cock. I'm not sure why "before the first", though. (Perhaps this is actually a reference to Mendeleev, who predicted gallium before it was discovered -- but "eka-aluminium" doesn't seem very "like a cock" to me.)

At the end you have to pay me 0.1$ ...

> Still baffled by this. Crystalline gallium is apparently made out of *dimers* (covalently-bonded two-atom pairs) so maybe there's a pun on "dime" somewhere in the air, but I'm not seeing how that would work.

... but the half could also be the beginning of the first.

> Baffled by this too. The half might, as Pat G observes, be $0.05 = a *nickel*, another metal not far from gallium in the periodic table. Maybe we're actually looking for an alloy (or something) containing both gallium and nickel?

None of the above makes any reference to the title, and the answer I propose is not a "devilish person". So I'm pretty sure I have at most part of the solution here. But

> the devil is sometimes called "Old Nick", which is at least suggestive of that half-a-dime...

Comment: Maybe it's more than a single element, since Nickel's in the same row of the Periodic Table?

Comment: As you wrote that, I was just adding a similar remark to my answer :-).

Comment: It occurs to me that I have been ignoring the title. "Old Nick" is of course the devil, and cocks/roosters have been associated with him from time to time. Hmm.

Comment: Or perhaps we need another of the elements discovered and named by Lecoq. Samarium or dysprosium. (Which gives me an extremely silly idea for an entirely different puzzle, but I'm not sure I can make it work; but that's another story.)

Comment: Good try. Gallium is part of the answer, you solved the second line,but the first line means something else. You need to solve all lines and then make another connection to get the answer. I will give another hint later

Comment: As another hint, the cock in the first line is not the same cock as in the second line ;)